# What does the tick mark `1 in the file name mean within the ASP.NET MVC source code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Looking in the ASP.NET MVC 2 source code there are several files in the System.Web.Mvc project that have an almost identically named file except for the `1 on the end of the file name.

For example, there is HtmlHelper.cs and HtmlHelper`1.cs. Another example is AjaxHelper.cs and AjaxHelper`1cs.

At first glance, the obvious answer is the `1 files contain the generic versions of their respective non-generic classes.

I'm wondering if there is something more to this naming  convention though given that we have other files like ReaderWriterCache`2.cs which contains the ReaderWriterCache file that doesn't inherit from any type of non-generic base class.

Does anyone have a better idea on what the naming convention is used to denote?

Comment: Are you looking at the sources download or the reflected source?

Comment: The actual source code downloaded from codeplex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number at the end indicates the number of generic type parameters. So, `ReaderWriterCacherequires'2` requires 2 type parameters, `TKey` and `TValue`. `HtmlHelper'1` only requires 1.

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC project has updated the naming convention now to make it more explicit, so you'll see `HtmlHelper.cs` and `HtmlHelperOfTModel.cs` rather than a back-tick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is even relevant, but here's some code snippets from a project:

```
List<UserAction> myUserActionList;    
DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
ts.MappingName = "List`1"; //ts.MappingName = myUserActionList.GetType().Name;
```

The last line contains a comment which could have replaced that line with no difference in behaviour.